# search through category names using search function?

Tags: simple-search

Is it possible to parse through and display category names using the search function? So, beyond simple channel entries I mean.

If so (or if this requires some kind of add on) could you provide me with details?

I have it doing what I want for a client, but they may want to be able to look through the categories as well. The reason for this, is that they're selling certain brands and they'd like for potential customers to not only look through the product name ('Apple Green') but also the brand ('Bendel').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highly recommend [Low Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search) which extends EE's native searching and allows for category indexing (name, description or any custom category fields). Specific link to category documentation [here](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/collections#categories).